# How to count number of times recursion is called? (Computing number of multiplications for x^n)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to increment count (mults in my code) in such a way that power2's counter is equivalent to power1's. My program compares the efficiency of computing x^n in different ways. I've looked up solutions on how to count the number of times a recursion calls itself but no matter what method I implement I get the incorrect output. Any help or guidelines would be appreciated!

This is part of my code so far (power1 has the right counter):

```
template <class T>
T power1(T x, unsigned int n, unsigned int& mults)
{
mults = 0;

if (n == 0)
    return 1;
else if (n == 1)
    return x;
else
{
    T total = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        total = total * x;
        ++mults;
    }
    mults -= 1;

    return total;
}
}


template <class T>
T power2(T x, unsigned int n, unsigned int& mults)
{
++mults;

if (n == 0)
{
    mults = 0;
    return 1;
}
else if (n == 1)
    return x;
else
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        return (x * power2(x, n - 1, mults));
    }
}

return x;
}
```

This is part of my output:

```
Test for integer base:
2^0 = 1: mults1 = 0, mults2 = 0
2^1 = 2: mults1 = 0, mults2 = 1
2^2 = 4: mults1 = 1, mults2 = 3
2^3 = 8: mults1 = 2, mults2 = 6
2^4 = 16: mults1 = 3, mults2 = 10
2^5 = 32: mults1 = 4, mults2 = 15
2^6 = 64: mults1 = 5, mults2 = 21
2^7 = 128: mults1 = 6, mults2 = 28
2^8 = 256: mults1 = 7, mults2 = 36
2^9 = 512: mults1 = 8, mults2 = 45
```

Comment: If you want to count the number of multiplications, increase `mults` only when you actually perform a multiplication.

Comment: @interjay I put mults++; just before the recursion statement, but I still get the same numbers except i get 0 at 2^1. Is there some other way I should be incrementing mults?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of recursions or the number of multiplications? Your question title and description seem to contradict one another.

Comment: Are you resetting mults2 to 0 between the calls?

Comment: @JustinRandall sorry, I want the number of multiplications - I thought the number of multiplications was equivalent to the number of recursions

Comment: @super no but I figured I had to do that somewhere, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset mults2 between the calls.

The simple solution is to

```
power2(2,2,foo);

//reset before next call
foo=0;
power2(2,3,foo);
```

Or you could make the function reset it automatically.

```
template <class T>
T power2(T x, unsigned int n, unsigned int& mults, bool init = true)
{
    if (init)
        mults=0;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        mults = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
        return x;
    else
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            ++mults;
            return (x * power2(x, n - 1, mults, false));
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: wow I didn't even think of using a boolean, but this works perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here: You are not resetting mults before each call to power2, and you are incrementing at the start.  This gives the correct results:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T power2(T x, unsigned int n, unsigned int& mults)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        mults = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
        return x;
    else
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            return (x * power2(x, n - 1, ++mults));
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int n = 4;
    unsigned int mults = 0;
    int res = power2(x, n, mults);
    std::cout << x << "^" << n << " = " << res << " - mults: " << mults << "\n";

    x = 2;
    n = 5;
    mults = 0;
    res = power2(2, 5, mults);

    std::cout << x << "^" << n << " = " << res << " - mults: " << mults << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2^4 = 16 - mults: 3
2^5 = 32 - mults: 4
```